# R order rows df1 by column names df2

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the bai.out and bai.in functions as part of the dplR library. To use this, the order of rows in my diameter data.frame (df1 in this example) must match the order of columns in my rwl data.frame (df2 in this example). However, I'm unsure how to reorder the rows of one data.frame based on the columns of another data.frame (in this example they're reordered numerically, but that is not always the case). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Example:

df1:

```
Name <- c("t1", "t4", "t5", "t2", "t3")    
Diameter <- c(3.2, 4.5, 1.4, 3.9, 2.7)    
df1 <- data.frame(Name, Diameter)
```

df2:

```
Year <- c(2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012)    
t1 <- c(0.8, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 0.7)    
t2 <- c(0.9, 0.2, 0.7, 0.4, 0.5)    
t3 <- c(0.1, 0.4, 0.9, 0.6, 0.2)    
t4 <- c(0.4, 0.8, 0.1, 0.8, 0.3)    
t5 <- c(0.3, 0.7, 0.3, 0.2, 0.9)    
df2 <- data.frame(Year, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5)
```

Intended output for df1:

df1reorderd:

```
Name <- c("t1", "t2", "t3", "t4", "t5")    
Diameter <- c(3.2, 3.9, 2.7, 4.5, 1.4)    
df1reordered <- data.frame(Name, Diameter)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can just make use of `match`:

```
df1[match(df1$Name, setdiff(names(df2), "Year")), ]
#   Name Diameter
# 1   t1      3.2
# 4   t2      3.9
# 5   t3      2.7
# 2   t4      4.5
# 3   t5      1.4
```

I've used `setdiff` to drop the "Year" from `names(df2)` but there are other ways to achieve that same effect.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I applied this to my actual data.frames, and it partially worked (3 rows were re-ordered), but for some reason it wouldn't re-order one of the rows. I changed the code to read: df1[match(df1$Name, names(df2)), ] because I already dropped "Year" by making it the rownames of df2. Is there something I altered in the code that would alter its functionality? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution

```
rownames(df1) = df1$Name
df1 = df1[names(df2)[-1],]
```

Then optionally to get rid of rownames again;

```
rownames(df1) = NULL
```

Comment: This is a good option to switch the names, but would it also change the values in "Diameter" so they stayed with their respective "Name"?

Comment: Not really "switching" any names. df1 is identical to df1reordered.

Comment: Great! Can I assume that if there were more columns in df1, those values would also be reordered to stay associated with the respective value in "Name"?

Comment: Yes, this will work in all cases given that all possible column names of df2 exists within df1$Name.